# Enable Multi Delete/Update in KeystoneJS

Tags: keystonejs

I've seen that KeystoneJS supports batch update/delete. (https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1810) I've tried running

```
KEYSTONE_DEV=true node your-startfile.js
```

But that does not seem to show the buttons in the admin section as shown in the image on one of the issues which shows some extra buttons on the top to select multiple items etc.

[Manage Mode Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAKrg.png)

How can I enable this feature?

Comment: What version of keystone are you using? 
At one point, this was disabled because it wasn't working. 
I'm looking at a site I've got live in production (so no KEYSTONE_DEV option) and there is a `manage` button. That site is running the most recent `beta.4` though. There functionality is currently only available for mass delete too, as update still needs work.

Comment: I wasn't using the beta. I guess I was just mislead by the issue having been closed almost a year ago at the time I didn't realize it was a beta only feature.